# Hover using arrow keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

In my project, I am adding `li` tags dynamically to `ul` elements and then when the focus is on `textarea` element, I am trying to generate a hover effect on the first `li` element whenever the user presses `down arrow key`. Somehow my effort is not working.

The code which I tried till now is as follows:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5hsCj/)

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="result" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
<ul class="autoComplete"></ul>
```

---

**CSS**

```
.autoComplete li {
    background-color:#E1E1E1;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.autoComplete li:hover {
    background-color:#BDBDBD;
}
```

---

**js**

```
var result = $('#result');
var autoComplete = $('.autoComplete');
result.keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        if (autoComplete.children('li').length > 0) {
            console.log('down');

            //should work with IE
            autoComplete.children(":first").focus().hover();
        }
    }
});
```

PS: **The solution should be crossbrowser (IE8+)**

Comment: why do you neeed mouse events? Why not just toggle a class?

Comment: @charlietfl I am not that much good in jquery. I hope you are saying the same what arunPjohny mentioned in his post below. It is working fine now. (not checked in IE though).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

CSS

```
.autoComplete li {
    background-color:#E1E1E1;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.autoComplete li.hover {
    background-color:#BDBDBD;
}
```

JS

```
var result = $('#result');
var autoComplete = $('.autoComplete');
result.keyup(function (event) {
    console.log('keydown');
    if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        if (autoComplete.children('li').length > 0) {
            console.log('down');

            //should work with IE
            autoComplete.children(":first").mouseenter();
        }
    }
});

autoComplete.on('mouseenter', 'li', function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover');
}).on('mouseleave', 'li', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gb6Ws/2/)

Comment: Hi, your solution is working fine. but just now I realised that the focus is still on textarea, though the hovering is happening on `li` elements.and even the scroll bar is not going down. Please check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gb6Ws/4/) for better understanding.